# DigiCert - Azure DevOps yaml task SSMClientToolsSetup@1 fails

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pipeline, digicert

Azure pipeline fails on the SSMClientToolsSetup@1 task:

> This installation package could not be opened.  Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a        valid Windows Installer package.

> error when executing setup task of STM Error: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe' failed with   exit code 1620.
> at ExecState._setResult (D:\a_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-    4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:942:25)
> at ExecState.CheckComplete (D:\a_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:925:18)
> ##[error]The process 'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe' failed with exit code 1620
> at ChildProcess. (D:\a_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-      4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:838:19)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

I am following these instructions:
https://docs.digicert.com/en/digicert-keylocker/ci-cd-integrations/plugins/azure-devops-client-tools-extension.html

Comment: I'm also seeing this since 2024-01-12.
Retrying gets it to work eventually. Seems to download a truncated file in the cases when it fails (we see `file after write  95133696` in the pipeline logs when it works, and a smaller number when it fails).

Comment: Also having exactly the same problem. Before January it was rarely happening, but now it rarely succeeds. I would hope for an update soon, but since their version 1.7 only have 417 downloads since May, I guess they do not prioritize it. I will try to find a forum and ask them.

Comment: @PeterWishart yes, retrying gets the task completed. I set retryCountOnTaskFailure parameter to 10, and it gets done after 2-3 attempts.  Sometimes it works on the first attempt.

Comment: @Tryggen colleague of mine is also working on reporting this problem through the DigiCert account.

Comment: @TamaraVučić Setting retry is a really good tip. As for now maybe going answer. I just put it as high up in the chain as possible to fail fast, and eventually I got it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task `SSMClientToolsSetup@1` is published by DigiCert to assist with setting up certificate tools in an ADO pipeline.

Part of the task involves downloading an MSI installer from `https://one.digicert.com/signingmanager/api-ui/v1/releases/smtools-windows-x64.msi/download`.

Recently this download has been failing and causing the task to fail:

> file after write  22288095 error when executing setup task of STM
> Error: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe' failed with exit
> code 1620

A workaround, as you suggest, is to change the task to include automatic retry:

Old task yaml:

```
- task: SSMClientToolsSetup@1
  displayName: Setup SMTools
```

New yaml:

```
- task: SSMClientToolsSetup@1
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 10
  displayName: Setup SMTools
```

For a custom build agent, I believe it would be possible to manually install the tools on the build agent instead (so they don't need setup every time, and can't fail due to a download error).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, the 'Install and setup STM client tools' task kept failing even though I had set 10 retries.

I've contacted Digicert support and they released a fix today.

For me, the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the fix? Or at least a version number?